# Show random string after shake in iOS via Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I detect shake motion via this codes:

```
  override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
      self.shakeLabel.text = "Text"
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, its working. But I need, when action shake motion, get random item in 3 strings. I cannot find this solution.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom/blob/master/Randoms.swift `array extension` for selecting random elements inside text array like `elements.randomItem()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare an array of texts, and do like this:

```
let texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
self.shakeLabel.text = texts[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(texts.count)))]
```

---

> after shake in 3 times, show random text

```
var shakeCount = 0
let shakeTexts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]

override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  if motion == .MotionShake {
    shakeCount++
    if shakeCount >= 3 {
      self.shakeLabel.text = shakeTexts[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(shakeTexts.count)))]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you. It's working! Welli how can I limit motion effect. So, after shake in 3 times, show random text.

Comment: May be you should open another question, but I added a example to the answer

Comment: Great! Very thank you. This is my last question: Can I basic back button for this view?

Comment: I don't understand "basic back button for this view". Anyway, I cannot answer this kind of question here, because I don't know anything about your view hierarchy. So, please make efforts yourself, and after that, open another question.